# How to write a method to access an entry from a SQLite SQLITE_ROW by column name and datatype

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, containers

I know how to access every entry in the row and I store it in a 2d vector.

```
    for(size_t j = 0; sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW; ++j) {

    columnCount = sqlite3_data_count(stmt);
    vec.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());
    for(size_t i = 0; i<columnCount; ++i){
        columnText = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, i);
        if(columnText != NULL){
            vec[j].push_back(std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(columnText)));
        }
        else {
            vec[j].push_back(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of a 2d vector I want to have a datatype where I can access the stored values by the column name and assign the correct datatype, for example

```
for(int i = 0; i<MyDataType.size(); i++)    
    std::cout<<MyDataType[i].fieldByColumnName("columnname").AsString<<'\n';
```

What can I use from the std which is c++17?

Comment: Is your question literally "what STL containers behave like dictionaries"?

Comment: @Botje, yes sorry. I am not very experienced with anything beyond the vector.

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [containers section of the C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: @Botje Is it possible to get the column name from the SQL Record?

Comment: [Yes](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html)